# How to set width over 100% using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, width, tailwind-css

I need to set div width to 110%, but it doesn't seem possible with Tailwind CSS. Their [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width) only specifies a 100% value.

```
w-full  width: 100%;
```

Comment: [Define your own](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#customizing-your-theme) spacing value in `tailwind.config.js`.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I was wondering if it exists another way without messing with the config file

Comment: Well you can also use [JIT](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#arbitrary-values) as `width-[110%]`.

Comment: I didn't see that in the docs, was right below, lol. thank you

Comment: @Jax-p feel free to write an answer i will gladly accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use JIT as `w-[110%]`.

JIT mode is default in Tailwind v3 and these values are called [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values).
In v2 you have to [enable JIT mode](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode).

Comment: I think you mean `w-[110%]`?